# Why PreDestroy method doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, lifecycle, predestroy

I have a basic spring project with simple configuration. This is bean

```
public class GreetingServiceImpl implements GreetingService {
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    private void init() {
        log.info("GreetingServiceImpl INIT");
    }

    private void destroy() {
        log.info("GreetingServiceImpl DESTROY");
    }
}
```

configuration:

```
<bean id="greetingService"
      class="com.example.hello.GreetingServiceImpl"
      init-method="init"
      destroy-method="destroy">
```

And this is my test code:

```
@Test
public void greeting() {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationConfig.xml");
    GreetingService greetingService = context.getBean(GreetingService.class);

    Assert.assertEquals("Hello", greetingService.hello());
    context.close();
}
```

When I run this code I don't see destroy method in logs as well as context closing.

```
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2be94b0f
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationConfig.xml]
com.example.hello.GreetingServiceImpl init
GreetingServiceImpl INIT

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried to call `registerShutdownHook` and `refresh` but result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure, haven't tested it, but have you tried making your destroy method public?

For testing I would suggest you use the spring testing annotations: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations

and then inject your application context or inject the corresponding bean

Comment: It's ok if `PreDestroy` method is private. `PostConstruct` method is private and it works fine

Comment: Yes, it should work with private. Just wanted you to check if this could be a specific problem with the Spring version you use.

I tested your code snippets with 5.0.4.RELEASE - and destroy method is executed. What version do you use and which dependencies have you defined?